# Laravel Websockets receive messages from clients

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

I want to build a basic global (no rooms) chat with laravel / node / redis using websockets.

I followed this tutorial: 
http://blog.nedex.io/laravel-5-1-broadcasting-events-using-redis-driver-socket-io/

Emitting events from laravell is no problem: I have something like this

```
event(new UserJoined('x Joined The Chat'));
```

This is called for my route

```
Route::get('/', function () { ... });
```

This is working well so far. This is my node server:

```
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
  message = JSON.parse(message);

  io.emit(channel + ":" + message.event, message.data);
});
```

And finally the client part

```
socket.on('test-channel:App\\Events\\UserJoined', function(data) {
    console.log( 'User joined', data.username )
});
```

The problem I'm facing now is: Can I execute php / laravell code when a user / client is emitting something? Or can I only use the node.js server for this?

Example:

```
socket.emit('test-channel:App\\Events\\Message',
  {
    username:username
  }
);
```

I would like to get the message not only to the other "chatters" but also to my php backend.

Comment: I used Laravel Echo Server for this and it was pretty easy to setup. I suggest you to take a look :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - as this quesiton was posted 2016 I already found different solutions. I found laravel echo not too easy to set up, but it worked for me. The missing "out of the box" websocket support is one of the very few negative points of php / laravel for me :)

Comment: Ops :) The question popped in front of me, didn't check the time! :) Now it's doing better for websockets than 2016 even though still not "out of the box"

Comment: It will be good if you can add your solution. it might help somebody.

Comment: Well, as I said, I used laravel echo ... however, this does not answer my original question, so I wouldn't want to set it as an answer

Comment: You can simply execute php code during javascript emitting event becuase at that time compiler does not know about php compilation. You can send a code in form of json and from the backend you can execute.

Comment: So you mean i `can't` not I can?

Comment: The best solution would be to use the Ratchet PHP library to create a websocket server. This library allows you to create a custom websocket server with a full range of features, including the ability to receive messages from clients. Ratchet also has great documentation and tutorials to help you get started quickly.

Comment: lol what? I mean this is what an Event is for am I wrong. Execute the event code while you have it in the php code then pass it on. You can do anything you want technically. I am not sure what you are looking for. Sounds like you are asking for the flow. fire event -> handled by redis -> catch event in PHP / catch event in node === (in parallel) execute php and node code.  Not sure I comprehend the question.

Comment: even more so you sound like you want a presence channel. Which in laravel you need to be authorized. you then want to create a whisper... like user is typing... but need more infor and 5.1 is not a great place to start.

Comment: this post is 7 years old and I do no longer work on this project - while I appreciate the fresh comments I probably won't have time to reinvestigate on this

Comment: I suggest moving to Pusher with Laravel it will be the best solution to integration the socket.

https://pusher.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your PHP application with the node server as a client.
So your websocket php client will be running as a separate instance
for example: https://www.piesocket.com/blog/php-websocket

or
you can connect your node js server to the database and save the message directly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as code examples, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the risk of oversimplifying, I understand that you would like to run some PHP from javascript in the end?

If yes, it's possible yet always via something else to the best of my knowledge.
Once you are using Laravel, you could consider Livewire, where the component has it's own (and very responsive) PHP controller that can react to changes made in the front end.

As you may see here, here's an example from documentation:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <button wire:click="increment">+</button>
    <h1>{{ $count }}</h1>
</div>
```

A click will trigger a function called "increment" which then is wired to the corresponding function on the components controller and will give you the results in "real time".

```
class Counter extends Component {

  public $count = 0;

  public function increment()
  {
    $this->count++;
  }

  public function render()
  {
    return view('livewire.counter');
  }
}
```

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart#add-counter

Other possibilities are all very much around making an api call to controller and react on receiving a success from PHP, I know it does not feel like "real time" making two calls but then I don't think the discrepancy is that relevant or even if anyone would ever be able to tell the difference.

I hope I was of any help, best luck in your endeavours and happy coding.

Comment: please replace the images by actual text that can be copy-pasted